# Unit testing a function's parameter that is a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, lodash

I would like to know how to write a unit test for a parameter that is a function in JavaScript.

For example,

```
_.forEach($scope.all, function(key, value) {
   $scope.arr.push(key.name);
});
```

I am able to enter the `forEach` function in my unit test, and am also able to access the first parameter, but I am not able to access the `function(key, value) {}` param.

Secondly, what is that function parameter called?  Is it just an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your unit tests, you shouldn't be concerned about testing every implementation detail. You don't really care about that anonymous function, but rather that the side effects or return value of your SUT matches expectations. You should test that `$scope.arr` contains the expected data after calling your function.

If you really needed to get access to that function, you'd have to use something like a spy to record when `_.forEach` is called, then access that argument:

```
var forEachSpy = sinon.spy(_, 'forEach');
yourFn();
var forEachFn = forEachSpy.lastCall.args[1];
```

But again, I would argue that testing in this manner does not add value and only leads to brittle tests that do not remain useful upon refactoring of implementation details. For example, say you use a regular `Array` forEach in the future; your test would break, but you don't really care *how* you loop through the structure, only that your scope is correct.

Comment: I am using karma-coverage package, and it's asking me to test those anonymous function. For the sake of the coverage % I guess that wouldn't hurt to do it. Although I agree with the fact that isn't needed to test this function but more the result of it.

Thanks for the example btw, this is what I needed!